# What's a good 30 yard time?

Tags: running

I'm a 15 year old freshman who ran a 3.54 at 30 yards. What would that translate to at 40 yards?

Comment: 30 yards is 90 feet.  Did it really take you `3:54` to run this distance?

Comment: That is very fast. World class sprinters cruise by 30m at about 3.77, see https://www.freelapusa.com/how-fast-can-usain-bolt-run-the-40-yard-dash/

Comment: Just as a quick note `3:54` is 3 minutes, 54 seconds. However, `3.54` is 3 seconds and 54 hundredths. Either way, it's either extremely quick, or extremely slow.

Answer (score 7):

You didn't run your 30 yard dash in 3.54 seconds.    You didn't even come remotely close.  If someone gave you that time seriously both you and them are deluded.

You would be one of the fastest 15 year-olds in the world if your ran a 3.9-4.0, and I seriously doubt you can come close to 4 seconds.  Your supposed time translates to around a 4.1 40 yard dash which would break Deion Sanders combine record (if Bo doesn't own the record).

Comment: @JohnP - No offense but you don't understand sprint times.  You wouldn't get to 90% of top speed until at least 20 yards maybe 30.  Your 10 yard split under 2 seconds is really really really good.  Running 20 yards at 1.54 is highly highly implausible.  Also something I didn't even touch on because of the laughability of the time is that a 15 year olds biggest hurdle is their slow first few steps.  Not until 20-23 years old has the fast twitch muscles developed for the ultimate first couple steps.  So  a 2 sec 10 is near impossible at 15.

Comment: Hadnt considered that. I was endurance/x-country in hs. Good point.